# Merge Multidimensional Array Matches

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on our order system to display specific orders that need to be done per department. I have all the necessary data in a multidimensional array. But I want to merge any arrays with similar values.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 16111
        [order_id] => 1234
        [item_id] => Product 1
        [invoice_id] => 98765
        [acc_id] => 1
        [name] => John Smith
        [phone] => 000000000
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 16112
        [order_id] => 1234
        [item_id] => Product 2
        [invoice_id] => 98765
        [acc_id] => 1
        [name] => John Smith
        [phone] => 000000000
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 16113
        [order_id] => 1235
        [item_id] => Product 3
        [invoice_id] => 98721
        [acc_id] => 11
        [name] => Bob Jones
        [phone] => 222222222
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 16114
        [order_id] => 1236
        [item_id] => Product 4
        [invoice_id] => 98754
        [acc_id] => 3
        [name] => Fred Bill
        [phone] => 111111111
    )

    [4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 16115
        [order_id] => 1236
        [item_id] => Product 1
        [invoice_id] => 98754
        [acc_id] => 3
        [name] => Fred Bill
        [phone] => 111111111
    )
)
```

We can see that we have 5 products to send to the customers. But both John Smith and Fred Bill want multiple items. Rather than store the data in an array per item, I would rather make this an array per customer. Based on the order id. So I would like the array to eventually look like so.

```
Array
    (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array 
            (
                [id] => 16111
                [order_id] => 1234
                [item_id] => Product 1
                [invoice_id] => 98765
                [acc_id] => 1
                [name] => John Smith
                [phone] => 000000000
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 16112
                [order_id] => 1234
                [item_id] => Product 2
                [invoice_id] => 98765
                [acc_id] => 1
                [name] => John Smith
                [phone] => 000000000
            )
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 16113
        [order_id] => 1235
        [item_id] => Product 3
        [invoice_id] => 98721
        [acc_id] => 11
        [name] => Bob Jones
        [phone] => 222222222
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (

                [id] => 16114
                [order_id] => 1236
                [item_id] => Product 4
                [invoice_id] => 98754
                [acc_id] => 3
                [name] => Fred Bill
                [phone] => 111111111

            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 16115
                [order_id] => 1236
                [item_id] => Product 1
                [invoice_id] => 98754
                [acc_id] => 3
                [name] => Fred Bill
                [phone] => 111111111
            )



    )

)
```

Product 1 is also Post and Packaging so i would then want to echo the data into a table. But I do not want Post and Packaging to have it's own row, but rather determine a field in the row of the other products in this array. So in a table we would see for example:

- John Smith  Product2  Courier(determined by existence of product1) 000000000

This needs to work if the customer has multiple products ie

- John Smith  Product3  Courier(determined by existence of product1) 000000000
- John Smith  Product4  Courier(determined by existence of product1) 000000000
- John Smith  Product5  Courier(determined by existence of product1) 000000000

Comment: So what exactly is your question? How to merge the array? or how to produce those strings (which I don't quite understand)? And have your tried something?

Comment: Thank you @passerby for cleaning my mess up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you look for something like this?

```
foreach($array as  $order)
{
    $orders[$order['order_id']][] = $order; 
}
```

It's grouping all orders by the order_id

Comment: This seems to work perfectly to group them all by order_id, many thanks for this. Any idea on the second part? The next bit would be to display the customer name, item, phone and then the necessary product. However I need another field which is method ie collection or courier. If one of the order_id arrays contains a Postage and Packaging Product ie Product1, then this field is filled in accordingly ie courier or collection.
So John Smith would have one row with the method courier. People who have 5 products and 1 P&P product. They will have 5 rows in the table all with the method courier

Answer (score 1):

So, if i understood you right, you want to apply some kind of grouping on your md-array?

Comment: That's correct, I want to group those array items together that have the same order_id, without losing any of the info.

Answer (score 0):

this will create the result as $target array. Assuming source contains the initial data

```
foreach ($source as $src) {
    $acct_id = $src['acc_id'];
    $target[$acct_id][] = $src; 
}
```